# React Native iOS build failed after react native upgrade

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Upgraded the react native app from v0.65.1 to v0.67.0. The build failed with the below error. Tried deleting the node modules, pods and installed them again and still facing the issue. The Xcode version is 13.4.1.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the error was easy. Checked the path to the project folder. The folder name has a space in-between. Renamed the folder by removing all the spaces in-between. Tried to run the project and it worked. Not sure why it ran with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

May be Xcode is using an outdated version of Node (in my case, it was because I use nvm to manage my Node versions, but Xcode used an old version of Node that I had installed via HomeBrew a long time ago).

By default, Xcode will use the Node binary located at /usr/local/bin/node. Check its version by running:

```
/usr/local/bin/node -v
node -v
```

If the first command outputs an older version of Node, simply delete it and replace it with a symlink to the newer one:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node
ln -s $(which node) /usr/local/bin/node
```

Comment: Replaced the older one with new one but still facing the issue